# How to get rid of verbose in the VS2008 output window

Tags: visual-studio-2008

My output windows is full of

```
The thread 0xe48 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x8d0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'xxx.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Users\xx\Projects\xx\xx\bin\Debug\xx.exe', Symbols loaded.
'xxx.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'xxx.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Users\xxx\Projects\xxx\xxx\bin\Debug\Magellan.dll', Symbols loaded.
'xxx.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Users\xxx\Projects\xxx\xxx\bin\Debug\Transitionals.dll'
'xxx.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.Aero\3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.Aero.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
```

messages.

Is there a way to tell VS 2008 not to show their own messages in the output window so you can spot other important things?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right click in the Output window when you're running your program and uncheck all of the messages you don't want to see (like Thread Exit messages).

Answer (score 0):

What other important things? Change the window to view your compile errors? Just change the option to "Show Output from Build"