# Random message "The thread has exited with code 0" in managed threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I've a got a problem with the infamous message "The thread xxx has exited with code 0 (0x0)".

In my code I have a main class called "Load" that starts with a Windows Form load event:

```
public class Load
{
    public Load()
    {
        Device[] devices = GetDevices(); // Get an array of devices from an external source

        for (int i = 0; i < devices.Length; i++)
        {
            DeviceDiagnosticCtrl deviceDiagnostic = new DeviceDiagnosticCtrl(devices[i].name);
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the constructor, for each generic device read from an external source, I initialize a custom diagnostic class that runs a thread:

```
public class DeviceDiagnosticCtrl
{
    private Thread diagnosticController;
    private volatile bool diagnosticControllerIsRunning = false;

    public DeviceDiagnosticCtrl(string _name)
    {            
        // Thread initialization
        this.diagnosticController = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.CheckDiagnostic));
        this.diagnosticController.Start();
        this.diagnosticControllerIsRunning = true;
    }

    private void CheckDiagnostic()
    {
        while (this.diagnosticControllerIsRunning)
        {
            try
            {
                // Custom 'Poll' message class used to request diagnostic to specific device
                Poll poll = new Poll();

                // Generic Message result to diagnostic request
                IGenericMessage genericResult;

                // Use a custom driver to send diagnostic request
                SendSyncMsgResult res = this.customDriver.SendSyncMessage(poll, out genericResult);
                switch (res)
                {
                    case SendSyncMessageResult.GOOD:
                        {
                            // Log result
                        }
                        break;                        
                    case SendSyncMessageResult.EXCEPTION:
                        {
                            // Log result
                        }
                        break;                        
                }
                Thread.Sleep(this.customDriver.PollScantime);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Loggo exception
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the above code in debug mode I always read 8 devices from external source, and for each of them I continuously run a managed thread to retrieve diagnostic.
My problem is that randomly one or more of the 8 threads I expect from the code above exit with code 0, without any exception.

I've started/restarted the code in debug mode a lot of time, and almost everytime one of the thread exits.

I've read somewhere ([i.e. this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054399/the-thread-has-exited-with-code-0-in-windows-forms)) that it could depends of Garbage Collector action, but I'm not too sure if this is my case - and how to prevent it.

Do someone see something strange/wrong in the sample code I posted above? Any suggestion?

Comment: At the moment you are swallowing any exception that happens... does anything get Loggo'd ? Note: threads exiting *by itself* is not problematic...

Comment: @MarcGravell I've put everything inside a "Try-Catch" just to be sure I don't miss any possible error, but I haven't logged anything ("Loggo" is a typo from my Italian original code...inside the `catch` I write logs inside a database). I know that "threads exiting by itself is not problematic", but my problem is that _I don't expect_ those threads to exit by themselves, at least until the condition `while (this.diagnosticControllerIsRunning)` turns false.

Comment: 'while (this.diagnosticControllerIsRunning)' is quite likely to fail immediate, in which case the thread drops out.   It's no good starting the thread and THEN setting 'this.diagnosticControllerIsRunning = true;' - you're quite likely to be too late - your horse has already bolted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'while (this.diagnosticControllerIsRunning)' is quite likely to fail immediate, in which case the thread drops out. It's no good starting the thread and THEN setting 'this.diagnosticControllerIsRunning = true;' - you're quite likely to be too late.

Bolt/stable-door.  Something like:

```
do{
  lengthyStuff with Sleep() in it
}
while (this.diagnosticControllerRun);
```

Answer (score 1):

Copied from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682013/how-to-cut-the-crap-out-of-the-vs2008-output-window)

> Right click in the Output window when you're running your program and
>   uncheck all of the messages you don't want to see (like Thread Exit
>   messages).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but my problem is not to show/hide the messages. The problem is that I don't expect those threads to exit, even without exceptions.